# Azure SSL Certs Can I change the subdomain later?

Tags: azure, ssl-certificate

I don't quite understand SSL certs. I have a website, [www.contoso.com](http://www.contoso.com) , from WIX, and then I have a subdomain, book.contoso.com , as an Azure web app.

I want to make the subdomain secured, and I was going to purchase an SSL cert from Azure. I was thinking that I might change the subdomain later, as in the "book." part. I was thinking that I might even make the subdomain my main website, as in point the "www." towards the Web App.

If I purchase the SSL cert, can I do this, change the subdomain and will the cert still be valid?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is yes, only with a wildcard cert.